# Trying to build a future context but my build method has an error

Tags: flutter, dart, statelesswidget

I have this code and the problem is that:
`'ProfileView.build' ('Future<Widget> Function(BuildContext)')` isn't a valid override of `'StatelessWidget.build' ('Widget Function(BuildContext)')`.

I tried to remove future but it doesn't work, any idea?

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_bloc/flutter_form_bloc.dart';
import 'package:maze/authentication/bloc/authentication_bloc.dart';
import 'package:maze/core/drawer.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

import '../../authentication/bloc/authentication_state.dart';
import '../../core/secure_store.dart';

class ProfileView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
  Future<Widget> build(BuildContext context) async {
    var state = BlocProvider
        .of<AuthenticationBloc>(context)
        .state;
    var token = await SecureStore().credentials;

    final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
    Completer<WebViewController>();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Profile'),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Align(
              child: Text("name",
                  style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: const CustomDrawer(),
      body: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Center(
              child: WebView(
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  webViewController.loadUrl(
                      "http://exemple.../",
                      headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer ${token}"});
                  _controller.complete(webViewController);
                },
              
              )
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: This is because when overriding a method it should have the same signature as the one found in the parent class, the build method in the StatelessWidget returns a Widget, not a Future<Widget>.
This method should always return a widget, no matter what the state is, so if you did this to make the screen build after the state is loaded, then you need to return something while it's loading.

Comment: @BaselAbuhadrous but when i change it to widget it give me this error
Functions marked 'async' must have a return type assignable to 'Future'.

Comment: yes because it shouldn't be async method as seen in the parent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that you wanted to have your build method as async because you want to wait for the token to be initialized, but there is a better way to achieve this and here is the solution:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfileView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfileViewState createState() => _ProfileViewState();
}

class _ProfileViewState extends State<ProfileView> {
  var state;
  var token;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    state = BlocProvider
        .of<AuthenticationBloc>(context)
        .state;
    initToken();
  }

  initToken() async {
    token = await SecureStore().credentials;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Profile'),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Align(
              child: Text("name",
                  style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      drawer: const CustomDrawer(),
      body: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Center(
              child: WebView(
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  webViewController.loadUrl(
                      "http:exemple...",
                      headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer ${token}"});
                  _controller.complete(webViewController);
                },
              )
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Read about the widget lifecycle, it would help you understand why you had the error in the first place.